# Ignore table if it exists on module install

Tags: 8, database

In my module I am using `hook_schema()` to create an empty (custom) DB table when the module is installed. However, there are some use cases where the module would need to be installed when the table already exists. This gives the following error:

> Drupal\Core\Database\SchemaObjectExistsException: Table example_table already exists. in Drupal\Core\Database\Schema->createTable() (line 594 of [PATH]\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Schema.php).

It looks like the module is still installed, but the error likely means that future install logic might not be executed.

Is it possible to perform the schema logic only if the table does not exist, or some other way to ignore the table if it exists?

Comment: `However, there are some use cases where the module would need to be installed when the table already exists.` why is it not cleaned up on uninstall?

Comment: It is. That's not the use case, there are others. For example, if someone wants to import this table before installing the module, or restore it after the module is uninstalled for future reference (both seem possible based on use cases I have seen).

Comment: `hook_schema` exists so you can say "this table belongs to my module, Drupal will manage it for me". The docs back that up: _The tables declared by this hook will be automatically created when the module is installed, and removed when the module is uninstalled._. The schema API can't be used for tables that Drupal doesn't manage (or at least not without changing how it works at a more fundamental level). I suspect you'll be out of luck here